# React Native : There are some issues with autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, autocomplete

I use a library **״react-native-autocomplete-input״**

1. The keyboard disappears after each letter is typed or deleted
2. The align of text from right to left in both the text box and the display of the autocomplete not works.

```
    <Autocomplete
                    data={
                      autoCompleteWaterSourceData?.length === 1 &&
                      autoCompleteWaterSourceData[0]
                        ? []
                        : autoCompleteWaterSourceData
                    }
                    placeholder={placeholder1}
                    value={querySourceCode}
                    autoCorrect={false}
                    onChangeText={setQuerySourceCode}
                    flatListProps={{
                      keyboardShouldPersistTaps: 'always',
                      keyExtractor: (_, idx) => idx.Water_Source_Code,
                      renderItem: ({
                        item: { Water_Source_Code, Water_Source_Name },
                      }) => (
                        <TouchableOpacity
                          onPress={() =>
                            setQuerySourceCode(
                              Water_Source_Code + ' ' + Water_Source_Name
                            )
                          }
                        >
                          <Text style={styles.autoCompleteText}>
                            {Water_Source_Code + ' ' + Water_Source_Name}
                          </Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                      ),
                    }}
                  />
```

Comment: Are you showing <Autocomplete ... /> component with a particular condition? Can you share the full code of render part of this screen

Comment: Can I talk to you in private?
Do you have Facebook or something similar so I can show you what my problem is?

Comment: I think editing the question by update the full code is all that need to verify if the error is what I thought it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refering your [code,](https://snack.expo.dev/@roei133/efc1a6) you can prevent the focus issue by calling function as function instead as component like below

```
// main screen
   return (
     <>
      <KeyboardAwareScrollView
        behavior={Platform.OS == 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
        style={styles.Container}
      >
        <View style={styles.MainScreen}>

          {WhereToSample()} // call like this instead of <WhereToSample />
          ...
          ...
     </>
   );
```

Comment: can you please show me how to do it i got confused .

Comment: Please check the edited answer and verify

Answer (score 0):

You can set text property `textAlign:'right'` both text input and autocomplete

Comment: its not works as you said ..
and also i edit the post if you can help with this its will be great coz the keyboard also disappear after  each type .